# What is <ns0: for?

Tags: html, xml

I was looking at this question: [How to remove duplicate elements from an xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117641/how-to-remove-duplicate-elements-from-an-xml-file)

It has `<ns0:` for ? I have never seen it before.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `ns0:` prefix for an element name is a reference to a (XML) [**NameSpace**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/).

In this case (the XML snippet I think you are referencing in the other question), the namespace in question was defined as: `xmlns:ns0="http://TestIndexMap.Employees"`  earlier in the document.

Essentially, with this line,  the string "ns0" (one could have chosen most any other string) is associated with a particular namespace, apparently one defining schema for Employees data of sorts.
Note that **the URI** ("http://TestIndexMap.Employees") **doesn't correspond to a valid online resource of sorts**. The XML Standard recommends the use of URIs for the purpose of ***identifying*** namespaces; that is because URIs are controlled and managed in a distributed and hierarchical fashion, preventing possible clashes, as would be the case,  would we use plain strings such as "employee_data".  There is no expectation however that the underlying URI would effectively exist as an online resource.
(BTW this particular URI seems bogus, i.e. doesn't include a particular domain, hence making possible albeit unlikely that at some point this document may clash with other documents using the same string for their namespace).

In a nutshell, **namespaces are used (*among other things*) to prevent possible conflicts in the names used in XML documents**.  They allow for example for a given document to include two distinct, say, `<price>` elements, or say, `closed` attributes, so long as one of them is prefixed with a namespace previously defined (and indeed even the one without an explicit namespace prefix belongs to a namespace: the default one).